# AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <TrainSupportVectorMachineClassifier> not found

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror, image-analyst

I am new to coding and do not know what I am getting the error message: AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment  not found. My first line of code is the typical "import arcpy....." I have already tried changing my CheckOutExtension from "Spatial" to "ImageAnalyst" and got the same error message. Any suggestions?

```
inSegRaster = "D:\\4.Peru\\Peru_Fall\\Peru_Fall.gdb\\_2018_updatedClip"
train_features = "D:\\4.Peru\\Peru_Fall\\Peru_Fall.gdb\\just_trees"
out_definition = "D:\\4.Peru\\Peru_Fall\\SupportVector2018.ecd"
maxNumSamples = "1000"
attributes = "COLOR;MEAN"

# Check out the ArcGIS Image Analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("ImageAnalyst")

#Execute
arcpy.gp.TrainSupportVectorMachineClassifier(
    inSegRaster, train_features, out_definition, 
    in_additional_raster, maxNumSamples, attributes)
```

The error message I get when running the above code is:

> AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment
>  not found

Comment: Did you ever actually define in_additional_raster?

Comment: Are you using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?